# How to modify the search result using the currentUser's attribute in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have a collection where currentUser inserts his/her Data.

```
Template.details.events({

  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    var name = event.target.nam.value;
    var age =  event.target.nombor.value;
    var gender = event.target.sex.value; 

      Data.insert({
        name : name, 
        age: age,
        gender: gender,
        createdBy: currentUser 

    });
}
```

});

Now, I want to show the currentUser a list of people opposite his gender. How do I do it? i am using the helper below right now but this only returns the males. And when I change the selector to "female" it returns the female.

```
 Template.dashBoard.helpers({       
        genderIs: function(gender){
          return this.gender === gender;
        },
        'people': function(){ 
          return Data.find({gender: "male"});
       }
    });
```

I have tried several ways but due to my inexperience none of it is working. here is the HTML

```
  <ul>
      {{#each people}}                      
        <li> <a href="#"> {{name}} {{age}} {{gender}} </a> </li>
      {{/each}}  
    </ul>
```

I have tried out something like this but it didn't work.

```
{{#if genderIs "female"}}
           {{#each people "male"}} 
               <li> <a href="#"> 
                      {{name}} {{age}} {{gender}} 
                    </a> 
               </li>          
            {{/each}}

                {{else}}

          {{#each people "female"}}
            <li> <a href="#">
                  {{name}} {{age}} {{gender}} 
                </a> 
            </li> 
          {{/each}}

     {{/if}}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to be adding a user's info to a separate collection called `Data`. Just add the name, age, and gender to the `profile` property of the user object and all that will just get stored in Meteor's Users collection. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users Then you can do something like `Meteor.user().profile.gender` to return the current user's gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what the comment said, you could save all the information of user in 'profile' field. So your 'details' template should change to:

```
Template.details.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    var name = event.target.nam.value;
    var age =  event.target.nombor.value;
    var gender = event.target.sex.value; 

    Meteor.users.update({  // using update method to update user information
      _id: currentUser
    },
    {
      $set:{
        "profile.name": name,
        "profile.age": age,
        "profile.gender": gender
      }
    });
});
```

---

Then, modify your dashboard helpers:

```
Template.dashBoard.helpers({       
    genderIs: function(gender){
      return Meteor.user().profile.gender === gender;
    },  // you may not need this function in your app
    'people': function(){
      var gender = Meteor.user().profile.gender === "male" ? "female" : "male"
      return Data.find({gender: gender});
    }
});
```

But you should pay attention here, if you haven't set the field "profile.gender", it would be undefined and always return "male".

At last, you could using the data return by dashboard.helpers easily:

```
{{#each people}}
  <li><a href="#"> {{profile.name}} {{profile.age}} {{profile.gender}} </a></li> 
{{/each}}
```

I wish it could solve your problem perfectly :-)

Comment: @Kaiyes It is equal to `if Meteor.user().profile.gender === "male" gender =  "female" else gender = "male"`

Comment: @Kaiyes Nope. It is a conditional operator in JavaScript. You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for more details :-)

Comment: also, if I store the data inside Meteor.users.profile , how do I return it?` `Meteor.users.find().fetch(); `  is returning objects with all the data in the console , but what will be the mongo call? return ` `Meteor.users.find({gender: gender}); `??? Its not returning anything

Comment: `Template.dashBoard.helpers({ 'people': function(){ var gender = Meteor.user().profile.gender; if (gender==="male") { gender = "female"; } else{ gender = "male"; }; return Meteor.users.find({gender: gender}); } }); ` I have tried using these but can't get anything!!! the html is the same

Comment: @Kaiyes You should do your query in this way: `Meteor.users.find({"profile.gender": gender})`

Comment: awesome, let me try that

Comment: `Template.tryy.helpers({
     'people': function(){
      var gender = Meteor.user().profile.gender;
       if (gender==="male") {
          gender = "female";
      } else{
        gender =" male";
      };
      return Meteor.users.find({"profile.gender": gender});

      }
    });`  here is what I am trying. I understand the basic principal. But I think I am not getting the syntax right

Comment: gives the following error message in console `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`

Comment: @Kaiyes As you see, the exception must happen at `Meteor.user().profile.gender`, so you should add an if condition to judge whether has a login user. If not, return null.